# Python returns list but to variable, but variable is null

Tags: python, function, null, return

```
def left(q):
    return q[0] 

def op(q):
    return q[1]

def right(q):
    return q[2]

def isInside(v, q): 
    if isinstance(q, list):
        return isInside(v, (left(q))) or isInside(v, (right(q)))
    else:       
        return v == q

def solve(v, q):
    if isInside(v, left(q)):        
        q3 = solving(v, q)
        print "**" # debug line
        print q3 # debug line. this prints "None" to the terminal."     
        return q3
    else:
        raise RuntimeException, "The variable does not exist in the expression."

def solving(v, q):
    print q # debug line
    if v == left(q):
        print "*" # debug line
        print q # debug line. prints the solved expression to the terminal.
        return q
    else:
        if op(left(q)) == '+':
            solvingAdd(v, q)
        else:
            return "v not on left of q"

def solvingAdd(v, q):
    print "solvingAdd"  
    if isInside(v, left(left(q))):
        q2 = [left(left(q)), op(q), [right(q), '-', right(left(q))]] 
        return solving(v, q2)       
    elif isInside(v, right(left(q))):
        q2 = [right(left(q)), op(q), [right(q), '-', left(left(q))]] 
        return solving (v, q2)
```

Above is a runnable but stripped down version of my program that duplicates my issue. If you execute this file in python and give it the command print solve('x', [['x', '+', 'b'], '=', 'c']) you will see the returned Nones that are giving me trouble.

*What these functions are supposed to do...*

The function **left** returns the variable in the first element of q.

The function **op** returns the operator in the second element of q.

The function **right** returns the variable in the third element of q.

The function **isInside** will see that v does exist on the left side of q.

The function **solve** will test if v is on the left side of q, which it is, so it will call solving to perform the operations needed to get v alone on the left side

The function **solving** will check if v is alone of the left side of q. If it is, it should return q to solve which should return q to the print terminal input. If it isnt, it will operate on the equation to get v alone on the left.

The function **solvingAdd** does the operations and returns the result to solving.

- q is a list datatype of the form ['someVariable1, 'someOperator', 'someVariable2']

*What the issue is...*

It seems as though my variable q loses its assigned value upon entering the shown if statement. I am going to give an example to show why I suspect this.

*Verbose example...*
Lets say I open python in my terminal and execute this given file and I give it the command **print solve('x', [['x', '+', 'b'], '=', 'c'])**. What I am expecting as output is the equation worked out such that it looks like **['x', '=', ['c', '-', 'b']]**. But what I am getting is **None**.

Now lets consider the solving function shown above. Lets assume that the rest of my program is correct and that is rearranges the equation correctly every single time. Once **q** has been solved to have **v** alone on its left hand side (q[0]), **solving** will be called 1 last time where the decision will be made that **v** is actually alone of the left hand side. This means that the statement **if v == left(q):** is going to evaluate to true on the last cycle and therefore **return q** to the mentioned **solve** function that will then return q to the input **print** command from the terminal.

The **print q** statement in the **solving** function actually prints the expected value of **q** to the terminal on the last cycle but, when python attempts to print the returned value (q), it prints **None**.

Any suggestions as to what is going on here?

~ Max

Comment: you are returning None as you have not specified a return value if  v is not equal to left

Comment: Can you give us a real, runnable, but stripped-down, `solve` function, and code that calls these functions, and show the expected and actual output, instead of trying to describe it in half a page of text? See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for what goes into an example.

Comment: Yeah I am working on creating a stripped down example right now that represents my issue. Ill edit the post when I figure it out.

Comment: The above code is now real, runnable, and stripped down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "solving" function's "else" branch is buggy:

```
else:
    if op(left(q)) == '+':
        solvingAdd(v, q)
    else:
        return "v not on left of q"
```

should be

```
else:
    if op(left(q)) == '+':
        return solvingAdd(v, q) #you forgot to return this value
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("v not on left of q") #this should raise an exception, not return a string
```

Also,

```
raise RuntimeException, "The variable does not exist in the expression."
```

should be

```
raise RuntimeError("The variable does not exist in the expression.")
```

Output:

```
>>> solve('x', [['x', '+', 'b'], '=', 'c'])
[['x', '+', 'b'], '=', 'c']
solvingAdd
['x', '=', ['c', '-', 'b']]
*
['x', '=', ['c', '-', 'b']]
**
['x', '=', ['c', '-', 'b']]
['x', '=', ['c', '-', 'b']]
```